# Downloading files inside the subfolders of a Main folder in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, download, python, file-download

I am trying to download all the files within 4 (or more) subfolders which is inside the main folder named 'Reports' in Sharepoint.

I used the following code:

```
url = 'https://HAHA.sharepoint.com/sites/Forms/Reports/'
import getpass
domain = 'HAHA.sharepoint.com' 
user = getpass.getuser() 
pwd = getpass.getpass(prompt='What is your windows AD password?')
 

import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
from urllib.parse import unquote
from pathlib import Path

 
filename = unquote(Path(url).name)
response = requests.get(url, auth=HttpNtlmAuth(f'{domain}\\{user}', pwd ))


for file in filename:
        with open(filename, 'wb') as local_file:
            local_file.write(response.content)
```

However, I get an error `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'AllItems.aspx?FolderCTID=0x0120001B8F714072E1184781C4A5E4969E4CC9&id=/Reports'`

Would anyone help me fix this? Thank you. I'm wondering if this code is specifically downloading one file. I want to download the whole folder and its sub-folders and the files within the subfolders.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59662472/download-all-files-in-a-sharepoint-folder-using-python
The URL is not a direct link to a file, the `'AllItems.aspx'` in the error message is a SharePoint page that displays all items in a list or library, not a specific file.